# Is there an analog of ArrayQ for datasets?

Tags: dataset

ArrayQ provides a nice way to check for missing data (specifically, it checks if the array is ragged).

But if you import your data as a dataset, and apply ArrayQ, it will return False for both ragged and non-ragged data.  If you convert your dataset to a list of assocations using Normal, ArrayQ will return True for both ragged and non-ragged data. [See screenshot below.]

Is there an analog of ArrayQ for datasets?  If not, what is the best practice for checking if a dataset is ragged?

[Sorry for pasting a screenshot instead of code -- when I tried copying and pasting dataset1 and dataset2 into MSE, I got a mess.]

[image]

Comment: I think the definition of what is "ragged" is a bit tricky, and it would help if you could show examples of what is/isn't ragged for datasets (which are made up of a mix of lists and associations, not merely lists). Have you looked at `Dimensions`? It might be sufficient for your practical purposes.

Comment: One way to think about `ArrayQ` is that it checks if any elements of a rectangular array of depth at least 1 are lists. If they are, it returns `False`. Otherwise, it returns `True`. Given that datasets typically hold heterogeneous data, do you really just want to check that none of their elements are lists? Or perhaps that none are even associations?